# .Net DateTime.Subtract Issue

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a function that returns the difference between 2 DateTime's in seconds. However, in certain cases its not working correctly and I'm not sure why.

I.E.:

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("7/22/2010 9:52:39 AM").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("7/22/2010 8:58:38 AM")).Seconds, "WTF");
```

The above code returns `1` ... obviously there's more than a 1 second difference between the dates above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` property instead of `.Seconds`:

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("7/22/2010 9:52:39 AM").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("7/22/2010 8:58:38 AM")).TotalSeconds, "WTF");
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to get TotalSeconds, not just seconds; the difference is 54 min, 1 second;

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the .TotalSeconds property. The difference in the two dates is just *one second* + plus a couple of minutes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing **just the seconds portion**. Try this

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("7/22/2010 9:52:39 AM").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("7/22/2010 8:58:38 AM")), "WTF"); 

// Prints 00:54:01
```